# pssh command with host name

Tags: linux, ssh

I need to execute a comand in parallel in several machines.
this can be done with pssh: 
parallel-ssh -h hosts.txt -l ubuntu -i echo "hello, world"

this is ok when the command doesn't require the hostname in the parameters.
But what if the command need the host name to run like this:
my_obscure_cmd --host 10.11.xxx.xx

How can i run this command with pssh?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are looking for possibility to start pssh with per-host specific parameters.
If so, the solution answer is in stackoverflow.com: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13677163/parallel-ssh-with-custom-parameters-to-each-host .